# HTML5 - 2017 right way to order <tbody> and <tfoot> elements?

Tags: html, html-table, w3c-validation

everyone!
 I've saw in many articles and courses that the `<tfoot>` in a table element should be placed before the `<tbody>` element. Right... But, when I do it this way, the validator (https://validator.w3.org)  tell me it's wrong, and that I can't use the `<tfoot>` in this context. So I decided to put the `<tfoot>` after the `<tbody>` and the validator don't found any errors in my code.
 So... What is the correct way to do it, anyway?
 I also found that spec that seems to be contradicted to its own: https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/tabular-data.html#the-tfoot-element

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<tfoot>` spec rules [were changed in December 2015 to disallow `<tfoot>` before `<tbody>` due to the accessibility issues it was causing](https://github.com/whatwg/html/commit/94d55af9cda601ce675d15f6a0e52c9bb9c6afa9).

As far as the W3C spec goes, the place to look for the relevant requirement is actually in [the part of the spec that states the rules for what is allowed in the `<table>` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/tabular-data.html#elementdef-table), which says:

> In this order: optionally a `caption` element, followed by zero or more `colgroup` elements, followed optionally by a `thead` element, followed by either zero or more `tbody` elements or one or more `tr` elements, followed optionally by a `tfoot` element, optionally intermixed with one or more script-supporting elements.

Notice that it says `tfoot` is allowed after `tbody` but no longer says it’s allowed before `tbody`.

Comment: For info of others (such as wordpress plugin developers) ending up here, the validator https://validator.w3.org/ will look at the websites doctype and redirect  to https://validator.w3.org/nu/ if <!DOCTYPE HTML>.      This can be confusing as the same table tfoot html will be valid or invalid depending on the doctype of the website it is being used in.   (obviously!)  However there does not appear to be a common tfoot standard valid for all doctypes and no way to determine the doctype being used as far as I can tell so far, before generating the table html.

Comment: Well, shame on me for being one of the only authors in the world (a friend of mine being another) to have enthusiastically placed all my tfoot elements before my tbody elements, I guess. I remember it being encouraged because it meant browsers could render the thead and tfoot in advance before starting to build the tbody(s). That said, I *will* fix all my tables in the interest of making them accessible, of course...

Comment: I guess the part about browsers being able to render the tfoot in advance is maybe something that browsers never actually got around to implementing, I dunno. I think maybe another reason was to facilitate pagination of tables

Answer (score 0):

A `<table>` element. The `<tfoot>` must appear after any `<caption>, <colgroup>, <thead>, <tbody>, or <tr>` element.  Note that this is the requirement as of HTML5.

The  element cannot be placed after any `<tbody>` and `<tr>` element. Note that this directly contradicts the above normative requirement from HTML5.

```html
<table border="1" align="center">
  <caption>A table</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">Invoice #123456789</th>
      <th>14 January 2025
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <strong>Pay to:</strong><br> Acme Billing Co.<br> 123 Main St.<br> Cityville, NA 12345
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <strong>Customer:</strong><br> John Smith<br> 321 Willow Way<br> Southeast Northwestershire, MA 54321
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Name / Description</th>
      <th>Qty.</th>
      <th>@</th>
      <th>Cost</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Paperclips</td>
      <td>1000</td>
      <td>0.01</td>
      <td>10.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Staples (box)</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>1.00</td>
      <td>100.00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">Subtotal</th>
      <td> 110.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Tax</th>
      <td> 8% </td>
      <td>8.80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">Grand Total</th>
      <td>$ 118.80</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```